# How to extract items with XPath that do not match a given pattern?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, scrapy

I am pulling some images with scrapy into a python list. There are some images which are placeholders and are identifiable by URL. So I would like to check on a specific string within my xpath command and if matched skip this image.

```
images = response.xpath('//meta[@property="og:image"]/@content').extract()[0:3]
```

I want to exclude all that match: `.*Demo_600x600.*`
How can I do this with xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```xml
//meta[@property="og:image"][not(contains(@content, "Demo_600x600"))]/@content
```

will select those `@content` attributes whose values do not contain a `Demo_600x600` substring.